# Primefaces dataTable - rounded corners - how to?

Tags: jquery, css, jsf, primefaces, rounded-corners

Testing my code on FireFox 18.

I'm trying to get rounded corners on a primefaces' `p:dataTable` table......

For this I'm using the jQuery plugin [Corner](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/).

I added to the end of my xhtml the following script section:

```
<script>
$(".ui-datatable table").corner();
</script>
```

However the table corners do not get rounded.

The xhtml for the table is:

```
            <p:dataTable var="row" value="#{myBean.rows}">  
                <p:column headerText="">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.name}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column headerText="Address">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.address}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column headerText="10 mins">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.gt10min}" />  
                </p:column>  

                <p:column headerText="20 mins">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.gt20min}" />  
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="30 mins">  
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.gt30min}" />  
                </p:column>  
            </p:dataTable>
```

The jQuery is linked to the xhtml, since the effect is applied on other elements when I try it.

What am I missing here?

Is it possible to achieve this effect by the jQuery plugin I'm using, or by other jQuery plugin?

Comment: Why are you using classes `ui-accordion` and `ui-accordion-header` for datatable? Datatable doesn't have that css class. Datatable has `ui-datatable` css class.

Comment: Sorry, you're right - my mistake. Corrected my code above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not familiar with jQuery corner plugin, nor am I in a mood to look at its source code to see where it failed, but you could also just throw in the necessary CSS yourself.

```css
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table {
    border-collapse: separate;
    *border-collapse: collapse; /* Fallback for IE <=7. */
    border-spacing: 0; 
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:first-child th:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 0 0; border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:first-child th:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 0 0; border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:first-child th:only-child{
    -moz-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; -webkit-border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0; border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tbody td {
    border-top: 0;
    *border-top: inherit; /* Fallback for IE <=7. */
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:last-child td:first-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 0 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 0 6px; border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:last-child td:last-child {
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 0; border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}
.ui-datatable.ui-corner-all table tr:last-child td:only-child{
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px; border-radius: 0 0 6px 6px;
}
```

And to get it to run, just add `ui-corner-all` styleclass to the `<p:dataTable>`

```
<p:dataTable ... styleClass="ui-corner-all">
```

Comment: @Balus, thanks will this work for Datatables rendering on IE 8?

Answer (score 0):

Provided that .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header are the classes assigned to the datatable you can do this -

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header").corner();
});
</script>
```

But you would be better off using CSS to do the rounded corners.

Comment: I tried with `$(".ui-datatable table").corner();` but it did not work.

Comment: Don't try with table. `ui-datatable` class is on `div`. Just use selector with css class: `jQuery(".ui-datatable").corner()`